# Pyspark - How can I remove the leading and trailing whitespace in my dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with 10 columns that I am writing to a table in hdfs.  I am having issues with leading and trailing whitespace in the columns(all fields and all rows).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Networks').getOrCreate()

dataset = spark.read.csv('Networks_arin_db_2-20-2019_parsed.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)

#dataset.show(5)
```

[image]

I use the following options that I have found searching around:

```
dataset.write \
  .option("parserLib","univocity") \
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","false") \
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false") \
  .mode("append") \
  .option("path", "/user/hive/warehouse/analytics.db/arin_network") \
  .saveAsTable("analytics.arin_network")
```

But I am still getting whitespace in my tables in hdfs:

[image]

Most of the examples I can find are Scala.  Is there a way I can successfully accomplish this using pyspark?  My version of Spark is 2.2.0.

When I query with 5 spaces after the first quote I get a result:

[image]

Comment: I think the spaces you are seeing here are because of formatting by .show(). Actually, there are no spaces as such. But you can do a check via where() Statement on one of the Columns and see if you get the desired result? I think, you will get the right result.

Comment: I have tested that and just tested again using:  select  * from analytics.arin_network where nethandle = "NET-66-219-162-64-1".  The results were 0. @cph_sto

Comment: That’s strange.

Comment: When I do: select  * from analytics.arin_networkwhere nethandle = "     NET-66-219-162-64-1"   Using 5 spaces after the first " I get 1 result. @cph_sto

Comment: It’s difficult to say without having a first hand look at the data.

Comment: I may be forced to bust out some Scala

Comment: Wait a moment. Why your 2 ignore options are set to false? I think, it should be True because you want to ignore the leading and trailing space.

Comment: In addition to that, use these two options while importing the data as well, as True of course ;)

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to keep it pyspark so I went back to the python code and added a line that removes all trailing and leading white-space.

```
df_out = df_out.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

This took care of the problem and I was able to import into an hdfs table with no issues.